# turn array within array into one single array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know if I have multiple array I can merge them by just doing push like

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(array1, array2);
```

but now in my case my array look like this

```
[[1,2],[a,b]]
```

not sure if there's a better method than spiting them and then recombine them or not.

I want to achieve `[1,2,a,b]`

Comment: @satpal at least give me a link!

Comment: Link is already embedded at the top [Merge/flatten an Array of Arrays in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: @tonyyew Use this http://jsfiddle.net/zkaef75x/